# Appcelerator - iOS app denied because of missing plist keys

Tags: ios, appcelerator

Running SDK 5.5.0.GA and the iOS app is being rejected by Apple because of the following privacy keys that I have not included in the plist:

- NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
- NSMicrophoneUsageDescription
- NSAppleMusicUsageDescription

I am not using any 3rd party modules or widgets and I am not aware what Titanium Module, Class, or Objects that would require these permissions.  I have handled the one for the calendar as I am accessing the device's calendar but I am not using the microphone, apple music, nor the photo library.

Is there a way to figure out what Modules, Classes or Objects that would be using these?

I know I can get around the rejection by just adding these to the plist but I would like to figure out what is using them and not just get around it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23925

Unless you request a specific permission, the user shouldn't see the xUsageDescription string you put in the plist.

In one of our usages, the camera, we just added all the descriptions and said 'This app uses your camera to upload photos' and resubmitted.  Its pending review now, so it passed the prescan 2nd time around.

Basically Apple prescans your binary on upload, finds some strings (method names) that it expects other things for and flags the binary.  This is how binaries get rejected for using 'private methods' when in reality it may just be a function named 'offensively' in Apple's mind.

Comment: The long and short of the JIRA issue is that if you use 1 method from Ti.Media, then all the methods are included by the compiler directives, thats what Apple is seeing when they look at the binary.

Comment: So then Ti.Media will be using both: NSMicrophoneUsageDescription and NSAppleMusicUsageDescription while Ti.ImageView will be using NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription?  I am using the Imageview to view remote photos and the videoplayer to stream live content.